# How can i make instances on faces real (single) objects?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I need every track element separated. How can i make this?

Comment: Ctrl A > Make Instances Real?

Comment: ha...that easy! Thank you!!! of course you can write an answer...i will accept + upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Make Instances Real*.The objects are still linked, to unlink go into *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data*.